# How to destroy growl div component that hides other stuff

Tags: jsf, primefaces

On my jsf page at some point I send a message to the growl component.

```
<p:growl id="growlLong" for="growlLong" showDetail="true" life="10000" sticky="false"/>
```

Once the 10sec is over, or dismissed by clicking the X, the issue that occurs is the element below the growl is not selectable. By inspecting the components on the page, looks like the actual div stayed there and blocks the content below it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div class="ui-growl-item">
   <div class="ui-growl-icon-close ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" style="display: none;" />
   <span class="ui-growl-image ui-growl-image-info" />
   <div class="ui-growl-message">
      <span class="ui-growl-title">Success!</span>
      <p>Configuration successfully saved.</p>
   </div>
   <div style="clear: both;" />
</div>
```

So, the question is - how do I make this to go away and keep the content below still usable?

[image]
Here is the screenshot of the issue, as seen with "inspect element", blue boxes are existing links, red box is the dismissed growl. Inside the blue box, we can't click the part that is covered by the red box.

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/growl.xhtml
says " Growl displays messages in an overlay. ", OVERLAY = "cover the surface of (a thing) with a coating.", As it says, the GROWL covers other component, even after being dismissed. Well... I need to get access to this component covered by the dismissed growl.

Comment: I will add a sceenshot shortly

Comment: I've added a screenshot to visualize it. It doesn't happen on the showcase page. So only on my page the growl kind of stays there, although dismissed. I've also posted in the question the code part of the growl that is generated on the page.

Comment: Since this doesn't happen on the showcase, and I can't reproduce the problem, my guess is that your css is missed up somehow, try to have a look on `z-index` you have on the surrounding parts, just open your chrome console and deactivate the css rules on the other divs, and see of anything would change, at least you can have a starting point. another point might help is where are you including your growl tag, in some cases I had with junior programmers where they placed the tag in wrong parts of the page, like header tag and so! try to include it in the end of your template/page.

Comment: As I can see that you're using foundation by zurb, if it's integrated in a bad way, the media selectors would miss up the components.

Comment: @urir, I use the PrimeFaces growl component without the issue you described. My first guess is that you are using something that is loading a different version of JQuery and thus, breaking the correct client behavior of the growl component.

Comment: OP's apparently not interested in an oneliner CSS solution. Too bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the it would be desirable to be able to tell growl to not leave behind the `<div id="growlLong_container">` structure in the DOM, the simple solution is to just select it and remove it using your favorite method to manipulate the DOM.

The ID appears to be the ID you passed to growl: `id="growlLong"` + "_container". With a DOM ID it is a simple matter of selecting it and removing it.

Yes, it would be nice to be able to get growl to not leave it in there.  However, there is a point of diminishing returns vs. the amount of effort you spend trying to find a solution.  It appears to be well past the point where you should just use a hack and remove it. Make a note about it, move on.  Leave a comment in the code that this is why you are making the DOM manipulation. A possibility rather than removing teh `<div>` is to adjust the `z-index` such that it is below that of the UI elements. Another possibility is to add `display:none;` to the style.  Obviously, code it such that if the `<div>` is not there nothing goes wrong. Verify that the next use of growl still performs correctly.

Ask on the [Growl discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/growldiscuss). Submit it as [a bug with growl](http://growl.info/reportabug.php). If a way surfaces to make growl not leave something like this in the DOM revisit the code and apply it.

As to removing it, if you have JavaScript available it is as simple as:

```
document.getElementById("growlLong_container").remove();
```

To be more specific we really need more information about your code and the environment in which you are running.

**A "solution" that should remove the `<div>`:**

Hopefully you will receive an answer which allows the elements to be hidden/removed by growl. However, there does not appear to be one at present.

The following script should wait around checking every 250ms to see if the `<div id="growlLong_container">` has been entered into the DOM. Once the `<div>` has been entered into the DOM, the script will wait 10s. If the `<div>` exists after the 10s it will be removed. The script is a hack. But it should work.

You will need to place it such that it makes it onto the page, either enclosed in  tags (as are here), or in a file without the first line:`<script class="code" type="text/javascript">` and the last line: `</script>` removed. If you use a separate file you will need to have it included in a similar manner as you do `jquery.js`, `foundation.js`, `foundation.topbar.js and foundation.tooltip.js`.

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        "use strict";
    const maxGrowlTime = 10000; //In milliseconds
    const checkFrequency = 250; //In milliseconds

    var intervalTimer=0;
    var foundGrowl=false;

    function dismissGrowl() {
        var growlId;
        growlId = document.getElementById("growlLong_container");
        if(growlId) {
            growlId.parentNode.removeChild(growlId);
        }
        foundGrowl=false;
        setGrowlCheckInterval();
    }
    function checkForGrowl() {
        var growlId;
        if(foundGrowl) {
            return;
        }
        growlId = document.getElementById("growlLong_container");
        if(growlId) {
            foundGrowl=true;
            clearInterval(intervalTimer);
            setTimeout(dismissGrowl, maxGrowlTime );
        }
    }
    function setGrowlCheckInterval() {
        intervalTimer = setInterval(checkForGrowl, checkFrequency );
    }
    setGrowlCheckInterval();
    })();
</script>
```

My hope is that you find an answer that does not require a hack such as this.  However, this should solve your problem, at least to an extent. With the script, the prevention of using those controls will last for at least the entire 10s up to 10.25s even if the user dismisses the growl early. With the two screenshots mentioned in the comments it would probably be possible to change the script such that it detects if the user dismisses the grow and then remove the `<div>` immediately. This would make it more responsive to user input.

This solution assumes that the `<div id="growlLong_container">` does not exist in the DOM prior to your issuing the `<p:growl id="growlLong"` and that it is not needed afterwards. This is very likely because the ID of the dive appears to be composed of the ID you pass the growl.

Mainly, this issue looks like a bug or incompatibility issue between components.

Comment: Of course it is abstract. The question does not give enough information to determine what method to use to manipulate the DOM (JS, etc.). A point which you clearly are well aware of based on your comments to the question. It also appears that the questioner is at an impasse as to how to proceed. Yet, the questioner has offered a bounty. Thus, what to do is not obvious to *them*. Small requests/comments on the question did not appear to generate significant improvement in the info provided. Thus, they need general information to figure out what direction to move to succeed.

Comment: The screenshot clearly shows JavaScript includes in the DOM, including *jquery.js*. If in addition to the current screenshot there were screenshots of that structure (expanded) in the DOM before the `<p:growl` call, and while the growl was being displayed this could, probably, be easily solved (hacked around). It is possibly solvable in that manner now, but without more information there is risk that doing so would disable growls, but probably not.

Comment: Your answering is clearly out of the scope, the question is about PrimeFaces, even though if the screenshot indicates some JS and if an expanded screenshot is provided your answer won't fit the criteria of the subject.

Comment: The scope of the problem is not defined by the tags.  The tags define what the question is related to. They should also indicate what types of solutions the person asking the question would prefer. I *hope* one is presented that solves the problem with merely an attribute change, or updating to a newer version. However, the scope of the question is: "How to destroy growl div component that hides other stuff". The text of the question does not state any solution must be implemented in any particular way, only that it must work.

Comment: This is a workaround. I *hope* a proper solution is forthcoming. --I agree, setting `redisplay="false"` is unlikely to affect this issue and may affect how it is being used in this case. It also is certainly not what the attribute is supposed to be doing. However, if you have been around issues like this for a while, you probably are aware that *sometimes* the unlikely shot comes in. If the cost of trying it is a minute or two to run a test then it is worth it, even though there is a very low expectation of it helping. If the cost is an hour or two, don't bother.

Comment: Makyen, thank you very much for your time and effort. Yes, this is a small issue with our code, and as such, the current hack/workaround solves the problem. Only change was growlId.parentNode.removeChild(growlId); so solution is accepted.

Comment: for some reason I can award the bounty in one hour, so I will be back for that.

Comment: I integrated the change you mentioned into the code so it is complete should someone else need it. I suggest you continue with asking on the [Growl discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/growldiscuss) and [submitting it as a bug with growl](http://growl.info/reportabug.php). It certainly is something that should not be happening. The issue prevents developing a usable UI; there should be a change made in growl to address whatever is causing the `<div>` to remain.

Answer (score 2):

This topic might be older but I just recently stumbled upon it:
The reason that the showcase is working but my version was not was that I gave the .ui-growl CSS class a height **AND** a width. In the showcase, the size of the container is only defined by its content and thus 0 if there are no items to display.

I moved my height definition to .ui-growl-item (which is more appropriate anyhow) and now it's working like a charm.

Comment: You can provoke the faulty behavior by editing the .ui-growl class in the showcase.